# Regex is causing part of a name to be dropped

Tags: php, regex

I have written a validation code for a name so that user input such as letters and whitespace AND apostrophes can be included in the name form field:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z' ]*$/",$name)) {
    $name = "";
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
```

I also have

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
```

in the same code because I don't want the engine to think that the end of a string has been reached when it in fact has not. But my problem is that when I am entering a name like Kate O'Mara in the name form field, what ends up in the data base  Kate O. Why is this happening? The regex that you see clearly has an apostrophe inside it (and you don't even have to escape it cause it is inside the character class). Why is everything after the apostrophe in the surname being dropped? The regex SHOULD recognise the full name.

Comment: Show us how you write data to database.

Comment: The regex isn't doing anything that could cut off the name at the apostrophe, I would look into issues around `magic_quotes_gpc`, print the query before running it, or - best recommendation - switch to prepared SQL statements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want the `$name` value to be _at least_ one character long, so `preg_match("/[a-z' ]+/i", $name)` would probably be a better pattern (`*` is to match zero or more chars, `+` is for one or more). It might also be better to match for one character that isn't allowed (possibly faster): `if (preg_match("/[^a-z' ]/i", $name))`... Don't forget that some names have other chars in them (like dots and dashes or names like _Mañuel_ or something... don't be too restrictive)

Comment: Why are you using on your if a variable `$name` and in your `mysqli_real_escape_string` you use the `POST` value ? Can you show how you create the `$name` variable?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: check the `mysqli_real_escape_string` call: its return value is assigned to `$name`

Comment: As a side-note, bear in mind that people can have hyphens in their name, too. Do not draw upon yourself the wrath of the world's Lethbridge-Stewarts. And consider whether your regex will allow Chloës to be your customers, not to mention Beyoncé. But yes, as others have said, your issue is nothing to do with your expression; the problem will be you not escaping your apostrophes properly before putting them into the database. Use a decent sql client library and parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in all, I think your regex is deeply flawed. Because you're using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, the apostrophe in *"O'Mara"* is being escaped (adding backslashes), which results in a failure of your `preg_match`. Not only that, but people with names like *Mañuella*, *Günter* or *André* don't stand a chance. Neither do people with names containing dashes (*Jean-Luc*).
On the whole, it's best to check for a number of chars that are *very* unlikely to be found in a name:

```
if (preg_match('/[@#$%*=+&![\]{};?]/', $name))
```

is not perfect, but it's a start. You have to remember that the internet is a place where people from all over the world get together. They don't all speak the same language, and don't all share the same alphabet (multi-byte chars!). Also think of our Asian friends. My girlfriend is Asian, and her last name contains only 2 characters. I can't even tell you how many times she's gotten the response *"Last name must be 3 chars or more"*.

All things considered: allow as much as you can when it comes to name input (without getting silly), and don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, but spend some time learning about prepared statements and how to use them instead.

Comment: His code doesn't do anything that would cut off the name though. If an espacing `\ ` is found by the regex, he does `$name = ""` so I would expect the database entry to be empty, not cut off. That's why I still believe something else is going on in the realm of improper `mysqli` query-building.

Comment: @funkwurm: OP didn't show us all the code, it's possible he's calling `preg_match` a second time, and using just the match as a value from thereon. Still: `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not the way to go, nor is the too restrictive name validation

Comment: Oh yeah I agree with the latter, prepared statements are the way to go for data sanitizing.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` escapes `'` as `\'`. And that's why it's getting cut off. ([Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php))

Also, have in mind that some people have hyphens (`-`) in surnames or can have special characters (like f.e. Polish `ąęśźćżółń` or german characters).